# How to make create-react-app auto build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I have been using create react app for a while. 'npm start' or 'yarn start' autoreloads works fine by itself but now I have an another problem. Currently I run the app on express server through the build folder, and I use 'npm run build' since express is serving the built files. There are many api calls which requires the app to be ran through this way. Now it become tedious to manually do 'npm run build' every time. Is there a simple way or work around to build automatically just like 'npm start' without eject the app(I know could eject and configure webpack to do that, but i don't want to go down that path)? Thanks

Comment: Cant you not split the concerns,meaning run your backend on express and your frontend development with npm start (webpack-dev-server)?

Comment: @user1185197 currently the frontend app has many api calls which requires the server to be running. That's why I am running the react app through the build folder. Is there a way to split that?

Comment: I dont understand? You have many api calls to several outside api's? If so thats fine. What are you actually doing on your backend that you require express? Some code would be nice

Comment: @user1185197 for example, in the react app, an example api call would be like  axios.post('/api/post/111'). When the server is running at http://localhost:8080, the request will be sent to http://localhost:8080/api/post/111. Did I do this part wrong? Is there a good way to decouple?

Answer (score 39):

Unfortunately this is something you will have to do yourself. You can use a tool like npm-watch to accomplish what you want though:

Install npm-watch

```
npm i --save-dev npm-watch
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-watch": "^0.1.8",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  },
  "watch": {
    "build": "src/"
  }
}
```

Afterwards, just use `npm run watch` to start up npm-watch so it can rebuild your assets on changes.

Update:

React-scripts now includes a `proxy` option that proxies requests to a different host/port. For example, if your backend is running on `localhost` at port `9000` under the `/api` route, then you would add this line to your package.json: `"proxy": "localhost:9000/api"`. You could then make requests as you normally would in production. (source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

Comment: thanks! looks like a simple way to achieve what I wanted

Comment: this works. The `pacakge.json` file means the file located in the project root directory

Comment: Docs here: https://github.com/M-Zuber/npm-watch I installed it and ran it, and there were no errors, but it seems to have no effect. It never detects my changes.

Comment: Interesting, can you try enabling legacyWatch mode? This falls back to chokidar to poll files for changes.

Comment: for me working with : 
  "watch": {
    "build": {
      "patterns": ["src"],
      "extensions": "js,jsx",
      "quiet": false,
      "legacyWatch": true,
      "delay": 2500,
      "runOnChangeOnly": false
    }
  },

Answer (score 16):

While this doesn’t really answer your question, **you shouldn’t be using `npm run build` in development**. Not only the rebuilds are slow, but it also skips important React warnings for performance and size, so you’ll end up scratching your head more and getting a lot less details in the warnings.

If you just need to do API requests with Express, [use the `proxy` feature](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) which lets you proxy API requests from `npm start` to your server. There is also a [tutorial](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#node) with a matching [repository](https://github.com/fullstackreact/food-lookup-demo) demonstrating how to do that.

In production, of course, you should use the build produced by `npm run build`. But you would only need to run it before deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the official answer Dan!

Comment: Both Angular (2.x+) and Vue CLIs support a build watch function for the build function. This is useful when the SPA is not self-contained. For example, if the SPA is hosted in within a view in an ASP.NET MVC (not dontnetcore as there's a template for that) or a CMS page such as Sitecore. In this case you'll want to build + watch your app in development mode so that you can view it within the host environment and have changes reflected on save without having to manually kick off a build. Unfortunately, debugging will have to be done in the browser's dev tools.

Comment: Seeing as there are bugs that apply to DEV only, it seems like sometimes you really do want to run production in development.  For instance https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12141

Answer (score 0):

Run your backend on a different port. If your running on express modify the file bin/www

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 9000
```

and in your /src folder create a config file where you configure your api host,routes, params etc

```
//config/index.js
export const Config = {
   protocol: 'http',
   host: window.location.hostname, //or the environment variable
   params: '/api/',
   api: {post:'/posts/'}
}
```

and in your calling component or where ever your calling the api's

```
import {Config} from '../config'

axios.get(`${Config.protocol}${Config.host}${Config.params}${Config.api.posts}${some id i guess}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found (as of 10/19/21) is to use [cra-build-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-build-watch).
Works perfectly.

Comment: seems to not work with react-scripts 5.0.1 anymore

Answer (score -2):

i am also using create react app, this is how i modified my scripts to run project for development(windows), build the production build and run the production build.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=8080 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "set PORT=8008 && serve -s build"
  }
```

npm start : run project for development(windows)
npm run-script build : build the production build
npm run-script deploy: run the production build

- npm install -g serve before run npm run-script deploy.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. :) OP wants to build the files with a watcher, in the means of building the app everytime something changes.

Answer (score -11):

1> npm install create-react-app -g
2> create-react-app Your_Apps_Name

Comment: Can you expand this into a full answer that included explanation of what each of these commands are doing and how this recipe works?